# associate array first element not starting from 0

Tags: php

My associate array is populated using a function. its first element key is blank, I need it to be `0`.

```
$blocks= get_data_ordered('blocks', 'page_id', $page, '', 'sequence');

highlight_string("<?php\n\$blocks =\n" . var_export($blocks, true) . ";\n?>");


function get_data_ordered($table, $condition_field, $condition_value, $limit, $order) {
include 'conf/config.php';
include 'conf/opendb.php';

if (!$condition_field){
    $condition = "";
}
else{
    $condition = "WHERE `$condition_field`='$condition_value'";
}

if($limit){
    $limit_query="LIMIT $limit";
    $i=0;
}

  $result=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM $table $condition ORDER BY $order ASC $limit_query");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    if($limit==1){
        return $row;
    }
    else{
        $output[$i] = $row;
        $i++;
    }
}
return $output;
include 'conf/closedb.php';
}
```

my current output is below. first element key is blank instead of 0

```
$blocks =
array (
  '' => 
  array (
    'id' => '2',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => '6',
  )
);
```

out put i need is to start with 0 not with blank key

```
$blocks =
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => '2',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => '6',
  )
);
```

please help me to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

Found the error : inside function `$i` is blank at the first instance

Comment: I don't think you need `$i` at all for array creation. Check my code below and try it.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you didn't define `$i` before the loop, it defines itself when first called on with $i++. And as mentioned by the guy who's living to die, you don't need to set the keys of an array if you just want them to start at 0 and iterate up. I would just define the array and use array_push() to put the rows in it.

Comment: Partially, and I know, I answered it yesterday about 5min after you

Comment: Ok, great, no problem

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1. First is like @AliveToDie commented above, you don't need to use
   `$i` for this scenario. You can use  `$output[] = $row;`
2. Second is if you need to use `$i` for your reasons, you need to
   define `$i = 0` outside of 
   `if($limit) {..}` condition